# Django models foreignkey group calculation

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models.

```
class A(models.Model):

  id = models.IntegerField()
  name = models.CharField()

class B(models.Model):

  item = models.ForeignKey(A)
  view = models.IntegerField()
  name = models.CharField()
```

I want to get the lists of A and when I get the list I want to calculate the how many (numbers) class B mapped with particular A and how many has viewed (view=1) ?

**Example:**

A

```
id | name
1  | A1
2  | A2
```

B

```
item_id | name  | view 
1       | B1    |  1
1       | B2    |  1
1       | B3    |  0
2       | B4    |  0
```

output: something like this.

```
[
{
  id : 1
  name: A2
  num_of_item: 3
  num_of_view: 2
}
{
  id : 2
  name: A2
  num_of_item: 1
  num_of_view: 0
}
]
```

The output results serialize like below.

```
details = A.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2])
result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(details, request)
serializer = ASerializer(result_page, many=True)
return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

What is the efficient way of doing it. ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage **[annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)** along with reverse lookups here, like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum
A.objects.all().annotate(num_of_item=Count('b'), num_of_view=Sum('b__view'))
```

Comment: Thanks. second part is will count the 1 or 0 ? how to put the condition to count the 1 ? by default it count 1 ?

Comment: Sum(Case(When(b__view=1 , then=1), output_field=IntegerField())). Thanks

Comment: actually you should use `Sum` for second part.